# PHPMyAdmin not asking for Mysql Password when installing on Debian

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, debian

I've apt-get upgraded, and apt-get install phpmyadmin but am
only prompted for the server type (apache2). After that it completes
the install without a prompt to enter my root password. I've
tried apt-get purge phpmyadmin and retried multiple times but
am completely unable to get it to work. I check the Mysql DB
and can see that no entries are being pushed in for the phpmyadin
database. Could someone please give me a hand troubleshooting this?

Thanks

output from install is

> debian:/usr/share# apt-get install phpmyadmin
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> phpmyadmin
>
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
>
> Need to get 0B/2887kB of archives.
>
> After this operation, 10.4MB of additional disk space will be used.
>
> Preconfiguring packages ...
>
> tar: ./md5sums: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:02 is 206420813.190455056 s in the future
>
> tar: ./templates: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:00 is 206420811.190030015 s in the future
>
> tar: ./control: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:02 is 206420813.189911702 s in the future
>
> tar: ./conffiles: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:01 is 206420812.189792603 s in the future
>
> tar: ./postinst: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:01 is 206420812.189660721 s in the future
>
> tar: ./preinst: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:01 is 206420812.189547658 s in the future
>
> tar: ./postrm: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:01 is 206420812.189438869 s in the future
>
> tar: ./config: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:00 is 206420811.189324406 s in the future
>
> tar: .: time stamp 2011-07-26 13:48:02 is 206420813.189251694 s in the future
>
> Selecting previously deselected package phpmyadmin.
>
> (Reading database ... 34698 files and directories currently installed.)
>
> Unpacking phpmyadmin (from .../phpmyadmin_4%3a2.11.8.1-5+lenny9_all.deb) ...
>
> Processing triggers for man-db ...
>
> Setting up phpmyadmin (4:2.11.8.1-5+lenny9) ...
>
> Reloading web server config: apache2[Sun Jan 09 09:41:10 2005] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
>
> .
>
> debian:/usr/share#

Comment: First thing I notice is that you are getting warnings about, consider fixing these by doing 'apt-get install ntpdate', restarting and trying again...

Comment: Restart as in a full boot down, or just reloading apache2?

Comment: Not knowing how the installer will behave, I would prefer a full reboot aka. 'shutdown -r now'

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400616/cannot-install-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`